# Class definition confuse in Typescript and ES6

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

All:

I am pretty new to ES6 and typescript and currently study both side by side.

When I come to Class definition part, there is one question:

Is there a major syntax between them in class declaration:

What I find out is:

In ES6, there is only method can be declared but no member :

```
class Greeter {
    constructor(message) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

While in TypeScript, it allows to declare the member variable as well:

```
class Greeter {
    // although it declare a variable "greeting" here, but I am not sure if it allows assignment initialization
    greeting: string; 
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the major syntax diff(plus access modifier, there is one related question about modifier: I read that ES6 class can not define static member, then what is the point to allow define static method?) between them?

If more than this, what else need to pay attention?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I think there are two things happening here, first, the expected "type erasure" of Typescript meaning:

Typescript

```
class Greeter {
  greeting: string;
  constructor(message: string) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }
  greet() {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
  }
}
```

will transpile to es6

```
class Greeter {
  constructor(message) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }
  greet() {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
  }
}
```

Which makes sense since TypeScript types are meant to be erased, and it is fair to assume that the "greeting: string" was just type information.

As a natural extension of declaring property type at the class level, TypeScript allows to initialize properties, which is something ES6 does not (requires to define/initialize those properties in the constructor).

So, this in typescript

```
class Greeter {
  greeting = "stranger";
  constructor(message: string) {
    this.greeting = message || this.greeting;
  }
  greet() {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
  }
}
```

which will get transpiled to es6:

```
class Greeter {
  constructor(message) {
    this.greeting = "stranger";
    this.greeting = message || this.greeting;
  }
  greet() {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
  }
}
```

Not sure why es6 did not allow properties in the class definition, but from a TypeScript perspective it would have been very odd allow type definition in at the class level, and initialize in the constructor.

Hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed add an assignment to property declarations, and those assignments *basically* occur right before other operations you've written in the constructor body.

```
class Greeter {
    greeting = "world!";

    constructor() {
    }

    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

console.log(new Greeter().greet()); // Prints "Hello, world!"
```

The flip side is you'll get an error if you use anything that's scoped in the constructor body:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting = message; // Error: 'message' isn't defined here
    constructor(message: string) {
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

TypeScript allows static property declarations as well:

```
class Greeter {
    private static instancesCreated = 0;

    static getNumInstancesCreated() {
        return Greeter.instancesCreated;
    }

    constructor() {
        Greeter.instancesCreated++;
    }
}
```

though that doesn't mean that a static method is not useful on its own. ES6 doesn't have instance property declarations, but instance methods are still useful because you can just tack a property onto the instance.

For more information, I encourage you to read up about classes in TypeScript on [the TypeScript handbook](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Classes.md) as well as in [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/classes.html).

Comment: Thanks, is the first and second code section are in TypeScript or ES6? Cos when I compile it with babel as ES2015, it give me error at greeting = "world"; line, which says Unexpected token.

Comment: Thanks, I guess one of my question is if we can not define static variable in ES6, why ES6 allow define static method?

Comment: As mentioned above, static properties are just properties that you can assign to in static methods or after the class itself is defined, the same way you would create an instance property in a constructor or regular method.

Comment: @DanielRosenwasser This code is valid if you are using the proposed experimental class properties syntax, but it is not valid ES6.

Comment: Okay, but my understanding is that the question was about TypeScript, and whether you can add an assignment to a property declaration.

Comment: @DanielRosenwasser Sorry for confuse, I try to figure out the diff between typescript and ES6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? If so, please mark this as an answer.

Comment: Your first example is not a valid ES6 code. It throws an error.